# Python per-seat license protection

Tags: python, license-key, hardware-id

I would like to create a per-seat licensevalidator for my python application. The python code is compiled. The goal is to prevent the costumer from sharing the application across his company.

Basic method

- Create a hash-string of the system hardware

  - How to do that?
- I will create a signature of the hash-string (license key file) and send the signature back to the user
- The application reads the hash-string and validates it against the signature

Maybe there is already a middleware solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "The python code is compiled. "?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is an interpreted language. That means decompiling of your code is always possible and relatively simple to do (using e.g [decompyle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/decompyle/)). And as a result any protection mechanisms you'll implement can be **easily** turned off. So:

1. Protecting your code seems like a waste of time
2. Python seems not the right choice for writing closed-source applications

Comment: It's not about to have a very safe protection. But my customer's company have to do something illegal to turn off the protection mechanism.

Comment: If they'll use it without a licence then it's already illegal. No matter if it's protected or not.